# Update ViewBag dropdownlist with ajax

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am working on cascaded dropdownlist with data passed with dataview.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.States = new SelectList(db.PLStates, "PLStateID", "PLStateName");
    ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(db.PLCitys, "PLCityID", "PLCityName");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetCity(int SelectedStateId)
{
    SelectList result = new SelectList(db.PLCitys.Where(x => x.PLStateID == 3), "PLCityID", "PLCityName");

    return Json(result);
    //return Json(ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(db.PLCitys.Where(x => x.PLStateID == 3), "PLCityID", "PLCityName"));
}
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#States").change(function () {
            var SelCity1 = $("#States").val();
            $("#Cities").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCity")',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: { SelectedStateId: SelCity1 },
                success: function (Cities) {
                    ViewBag.Cities = Cities;

                    $("#Cities").append('Cities');
                    alert("success" + Cities);
             },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });

</script>

<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("States", "Select one")
    @Html.DropDownList("Cities", "Select one")
</div>
```

In alert i can see the json gives back objects but the Cities dropdownlist becomes emptied with no value inside. Why ddl.cities is not filled with retured values??

Additional question is how to add style to dropdownlist??

Comment: You seem to be mixing server-side and client-side code, you can't set `ViewBag` properties in JavaScript.  Also, you're just appending the string "Cities" to the `select` element, you're not actually appending any HTML to it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually add options to the cities drop down via js with the Json data returned from the controller.

As far as styling. You can style in inline by adding a "style"= to the html attributes or style with external css class using the @class html attribute.